# Convergence of Minima of Converging Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose that $X_{ij}$ is a set of iid Rademacher random variables with $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$.  We know that by the law of large numbers, for each row of this array, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{ij}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely.  Similarly, if we took an infinimum over a finite set of rows, that would also converge to $0$ almost surely.  I'm wondering what happens when we take an infimum of $f(n)$ rows as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  Formally, if
$$Y_{n} = \inf_{i=1,\ldots,f(n)}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{ij}\,,$$
then what can we say about convergence of $Y_{n}$ to a limit?

If $f(n)$ grows very slowly, $Y_{n}$ may still tend to $0$.  I'm most interested in whether it's possible to get $Y_{n}$ to converge almost surely to a constant less than $0$.

Comment: How do you get to $-\infty$? I think each of the terms in the infimum is $\geq -1$.

Comment: My naïve guess is that, if $f(n)=\mathcal{O}(n)$ then the minimum is still within the CLT regime, hence the minimum will behave like the minimum of their respective normal approximations. As such, the behavior of $Y_n$ may be studied using the extreme value theory. For instance, if $f(n)=n$ then I suspect (based on heuristics as well as simulation) that $$\frac{n}{2}Y_n^2-\log n$$ will converge in distribution to a Weibull distribution.

Comment: @PhoemueX Definitely, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we assume $\{X_{ij}\}$ are i.i.d. with $$P[X_{ij}=-1]=P[X_{ij}=1]=1/2$$
Define
$$M_n^{(i)} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}$$
For each positive integer $n$, $\{M_n^{(i)}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.).
Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $E[X_{ij}]=0$ for all $i,j$, by the [Chernov-Hoeffding bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality):
$$P[M_n^{(i)}\leq -\epsilon] \leq e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$$

Assume $f(n)$ is a positive integer for each $n$. Define $Y_n = \inf_{i \in \{1, ..., f(n)\}} M_n^{(i)}$.  Then
\begin{align}
P[Y_n> -\epsilon] &= P[M_n^{(1)}> -\epsilon]^{f(n)} \\&\geq (1-e^{-n\epsilon^2/2})^{f(n)}\\
&\geq 1 - f(n)e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}
\end{align}
where the last inequality uses [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) .
Thus
$$P[Y_n \leq -\epsilon] \leq f(n)e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$$
If $f(n)$ grows sub-exponentially, the right-hand-side goes to 0 for any $\epsilon>0$.

---

**For convergence to 0:**

Suppose $f(n)$ grows slowly enough so that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}<\infty$$
This is true, for example, for $f(n)=n^k$ for any positive integer $k$.  Then by Borel-Cantelli we get $\{Y_n\leq -\epsilon\}$ finitely often (almost surely).  This holds for all $\epsilon>0$ and so
$$ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} Y_n \geq 0 \quad \mbox{(almost surely)} $$
On the other hand, it is easy to see that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} Y_n \leq 0$ almost surely,
so we get
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Y_n = 0 \quad \mbox{(almost surely)}$$

---

**For convergence to -1:**

We know $-1\leq M_n^{(i)}\leq 1$ and $-1\leq Y_n\leq 1$ for all $i, n$. So
$$P[M_n^{(i)}=-1] = (1/2)^n \quad \forall n, i$$
Then
$$P[Y_n > -1] = (1-(1/2)^n)^{f(n)}$$
In particular if $f(n)=2^n$ then
$$ P[Y_n>-1] = (1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{2^n} \approx 1/e$$
where the $1/e$ approximation is accurate for large $n$.
If we assume $f(n)$ grows rapidly enough to ensure
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{f(n)}<\infty$$
(which is true, for example, if $f(n)=n2^n$),
then $\{Y_n>-1\}$ finitely often almost surely, and
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_n = -1 \quad \mbox{(almost surely)}$$

Comment: Great answer.  Do you have any thoughts about how $Y_{n}$ behaves in the limit when $f(n)$ is in between the two growth rates you determined?  I'm particularly interesting in whether $f(n)$ exists to make $Y_{n}$ converge almost surely to a constant $c\in (-1,0)$.  I don't know whether I should expect $Y_{n}$ to always converge almost surely or whether it will be a non-deterministic random variable on $[-1,0]$ for the growth rates between those you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to appeal to independence and Bernoulli's inequality to show that $\mathbb{P}(Y_{n} < -\epsilon) \le f(n)e^{-n\epsilon^{2}/2}$.  You can get that directly with a union bound, since $Y_{n} < c$ when some row average is $ < c$, and that probability is bounded by the sum of the probabilities that a row average is $ < c$.  I just think this is worth pointing out since some of this argument doesn't require independence of the rows of the array $X_{ij}$.

Comment: True, the final bound on that first part for convergence to 0 does not require independence between rows and can be achieved by the union bound.  The tighter bound $(1-e^{-n\epsilon^2/2})^{f(n)}$ derived along the way for that part does use independence, and that may still be helpful for the "intermediate growth rate" scenario you describe.